# Django Form for voting

Tags: python, django

I have a web form that has two fields:

- `gender`: male or female
- `diseases`: HIV, Malaria, Typhoid

I have created a vote submit button. I want this vote button to point to another form that records the user choices (for `gender` and `diseases`) e.g the number of males and females that have HIV, CHOLERA (diseases field) etc.

How do I go about this?

Example of Output:

```
Male-cholera-2
Male-Thypoid-5
Female-HIV-4
Female-Cholera-3
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from . models import MyModel
from . forms import MyModelForm

class CreateMyModelView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'poll/template.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.CreateMyModelView.as_view(), name='abc'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

Gender = (
    ('male', 'MALE'),
    ('female', 'FEMALE'),
)
Diseases = (
    ('cholera', 'CHOLERA'),
    ('hiv', 'HIV'),
    ('Malaria', 'MALARIA'),
    ('Typhoid', 'TYPHOID'),
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Gender, default='MALE')
    Diseases = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=Diseases, default='MALARIA')
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import MyModel
from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['Gender', 'Diseases']
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'poll/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
<h1></h1>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `MyModel.objects.filter(Gender="MALE",Diseases="MALARIA").count()` would give you how many males have malaria

Comment: But that's making it hardcoded...I need flexibility that automatically records the user's choice

Comment: `collections.Counter((obj.Gender,obj.Diseases) for obj in MyModel.objects.all())` I think would work